# SQLite for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, system.data.sqlite

i have installed System.Data.SQlite ([Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1)](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)) on visual studio 2013. When i try to add System.Data.SQlite as a reference it isn't shown as a reference dll in the window. In visual studio 2010,2012 it can be added as a reference. What is the reason for this? How can i use Sqlite in visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling `using SQLite;`.
Forgive me if I'm wrong. I am new to SQlite too.

Comment: No bro i'm trying to add System.Data.SQlite as a reference.